# Declare data member as primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, struts

I have 2 Entity classes User and Address

```
@Entity
class User
{
    int id;
    String name;
}

@Entity
class Vehicle
{
    @OneToOne
    User user;
    String vehName; 
}
```

I want to declare "user" data member in Vehicle class as primary key..can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Did you try to google the solution?

Comment: yes..I tried...but unfortunately couldn't find the solution

Comment: Do you want to use `id` and `name` as composite key, or you are having `User` as foreign key in `Vehicle`?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617):

> Finally, you can ask Hibernate to copy the identifier from another
>   associated entity. In the Hibernate jargon, it is known as a foreign
>   generator but the JPA mapping reads better and is encouraged.

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```

> Or alternatively

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id Integer id;

  @MapsId @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```